# SQLserver don't send notifications with service broker

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to get my application notified if there is any change in my sql server db and I'm using Table dependency to get them. I'm working with a DB that I didn't created (it's sql server 2008R2) and it don't send the messages generated by the service broker, but in the same connection and with a different db generated by me and the same structure of table it sends the service broker messages to my application. Is there anything I need to change to allow SQLserver to send the messages?

Comment: Make sure Service Broker is enabled in the problem databases: `SELECT name, is_broker_enabled FROM sys.databases;`.

Comment: @DanGuzman I did it and it returns me a 1.